# I want to get the single value from a arraylist in a string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

```
public ArrayList ChequeACpayee(string Payee, DateTime Date)
{
    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ViewChequeforAcPayee", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter();
        p = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayeeName", Payee);
        p = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ChequeInfo infoCheque = new ChequeInfo();

            infoCheque.AcPayee = dr["AcPayee"].ToString();

            arr.Add(infoCheque);
        }

        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    return arr;
}
ArrayList ArrAcpayee = ChequeAcPayee.ChequeACpayee (DDLPayee.SelectedItem.ToString(), BDPSelectDate.SelectedDate);
```

How do I get the single value from this arraylist? The value must be a converted to a string.

Comment: What value any? is their criteria.

Comment: Any reason you're not using generics?

Comment: @rahul, can you tell clearly what do you want from arraylist?

Comment: from this i have getting AcPayee .  i want to get this arraylist value in string

Comment: Any chance I could convince you to use List<string> instead of ArrayList?

Answer (score 7):

You could just use the indexer and a cast:

```
string payee = (string) ArrAcpayee[0];
```

But you should probably check the size first:

```
if (ArrAcpayee.Length != 1)
{
    // Create your own more appropriate exception
    throw new SomethingWentWrongException("Expected 1 payee entry; got "
                                          + ArrAcpayee.Length);
}
string payee = (string) ArrAcpayee[0];
```

However, I'm concerned about other aspects of your code:

- Is there some reason you're not using generics? Are you *really* using .NET 1.1, or some framework which doesn't support `List<T>`?
- Do you ever expect there to be more than one result, within the `ChequeACpayee` method? If not, that method should return a string and throw if there isn't exactly one result
- Catching an exception and just swallowing it is a *really* bad idea. Do you really want to keep going as if nothing had gone wrong *whatever happens*?
- You should use `using` statements to close your database connection and data reader, instead of calling `Close()` manually. Otherwise if an exception is thrown, you'll leak the connection.
- Conventionally, parameters are camelCased, not PascalCased. (Local variables are invisible from outside the class, so less of an issue, but they're generally camelCased too.)

Comment: I get an error: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.String'"

Comment: @HammanSamuel: Then your object is clearly of type `Object[]` rather than `String`. It seems unlikely that you've got the exact same code as someone nearly 3 years ago... I suggest you ask a new question if you can't work out why your object is the wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using linq:

```
ArrayList ArrAcpayee = ChequeAcPayee.ChequeACpayee (DDLPayee.SelectedItem.ToString(), BDPSelectDate.SelectedDate);

return ArrAcpayee.Cast<string>().Single(); //If there will always be just one value in the array list

return ArrAcpayee.Cast<string>().SingleOrDefault(); //If there will be either one or no value in the array list

return ArrAcpayee.Cast<string>().First(); //If you want to return the first value
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This won't compile, because ArrayList isn't generic. You'd need to use `Cast<String>()` or `OfType<String>()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some build in methods in SqlDataReader that enables you to do that:

dr.[GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx)(dr.[GetOrdinal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal.aspx)("AcPayee"));